# Can a parameter be passed to a function that is set as an object literal value?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, parameter-passing, object-literal

I have a function, **functionWithDifferentScope**, that takes an object, **myobject.options**, as a parameter. One of the pairs in the **options** object is a callback which points to a function defined in **myObject**: **myCallback**.

What I'm trying to achieve is injection of the **myObject** *namespace* into the callback of a function that is defined (by a 3rd party) at the global level.

A simplified example:

```
var myObject = {
    options: {
        callback: this.myCallback(this),
        ...,
    },

    init: function() {
        // functionWithDifferentScope operates in the 'window' context
        functionWithDifferentScope(this.options);
    },

    myCallback: function(namespace) {
        // 'this' is window
        // 'namespace' is myObject
    }
}

myObject.init();
```

When executing this script, **this.myCallback(this)** appears to be executed at definition (due to the parenthesis?); as well as once **myObject.init();** is caled. During the first executions *this* is **myObject**, but subsequent calls through the **functionWithDifferentScope** identify *this* as **window**.

Is there a way to pass the **myObject** *namespace* to the **myObject.options.callback** value as a parameter?

Comment: To call functionWithDifferentScope(this.options); with a context or your choice you can use functionWithDifferentScope.call(this, this.options); ..is that what you want ?

Comment: @Robert `functionWithDifferentScope` operates at the global level, so giving it the local `this` breaks other parts of the function. I was looking for a way to pass the `this` to just a single callback; if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you give some usage example with annotation of what you expect context etc to be. I have an idea of what you want but you might need to rewrite myObject a little to be able to modify the options a bit more easily

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is prototype style "bind"

Basically "this.myCallback(this)" is a call to the function.

this.myCallback is the function itself. (It is an object with the type function).

You can call it using the method 'call' or 'apply' that you can use on functions. Which will call these functions.

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fapply

The first argument is the object context to work in. What I think you mean by object namespace.

so: `a.callback(5)` is the same as `a.callback.call(a,5)`

However please note that these days if you are working with most javascript libraries you probably have a 'bind' function that will do the work for you.

http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/bind/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

the idea is that `this.callback.bind(this)` returns a Function object you can call that will inject the correct context automatically so you can pass the return value of bind alone as a callback and be assured that the method will be executed on the correct object.

Comment: So yes, I'm looking for something similar, but instead of giving the calling function `this`, I want to give only the callback `this`

Comment: Bind is your friend. It is a utility function that was introduced by Prototype.js and got quite popular so it made it into other libraries and newer implementations of Javascript itself

I have an object Dog that has a method Bark, and I want to pass a Function object that will call the Method Bark on the Dog object so:

var f = dog.bark.bind(dog) returns a Function object.

Anyone who calls f.call() is doing the same as calling:
dog.bark.call(dog)

Comment: So from Javascript 5 you will have bind in the language:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

See the first example in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
var myObject = new (function() {
    var t = this;

    vac callback = function() {
        // t equals to the myObject-instance
        // this equals to window
    }

    this.init = function() {
        funcWithDifferencScope(callback);
    }
})();

myObject.init();
```